# Matlab's "hold on" in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia

I'm just looking for an equivalent of Matlab's `hold on` command in Julia.

I have `x` Array that is 15x1 and `y` Array 15x6, so this will make 6 plots all at once. What I want to do is plot each `y[:,1],y[:,2],...,y[:,6]` one at a time (pausing say 5 seconds between each one) for a better illustration of convergence of a numerical method rather than just slapping all 6 iterations on there at once.

I'm using the `pyplot` backend with the Plots.jl package.

Answer (score 11):

Call `plot!` instead of `plot`. For example

```
using Plots
pyplot()
plot!(rand(10))
plot!(rand(10))
```

Comment: and use `sleep` for the pause